# How to find this particular hot water heat pump?

Tags: hvac

I have this pump pictured attached to my furnace. I actually have two of them. This one, however, is on a circuit that has been empty for a few years and is now rusted shut and needs replacing. I have a plumber coming to replace it and just took their word at the cost, but then I got to thinking that I should maybe do a quick web search for comparison.

It seems that Grudfos makes a whole lot of these types of pumps. Pexsupply sells quite a few of them:

http://www.pexsupply.com/Grundfos-Pumps-1838000?gclid=COT0xt2Fg6wCFacEQAodSBGHNw

Alas, I really have no idea how to determine which (if any) is a match to the one I have. Can anyone tell if the pump I have matches any on that site? If not, anyone know if the pump I have is still being manufactured and, if so, what it might cost?

[image: GRUNDFOS pump]

Comment: I would think the "type" would give you a general idea "UP 15-42 F", and would guess [this one](http://www.pexsupply.com/Grundfos-59896155-UP15-42F-Circulator-Pump-1-25-HP-115-volt-5571000-p) would be comparable.

Comment: I think Tester101 has got it. One thing to keep in mind: even if this pump is still manufactured, your plumber may not be able to install it because (a) he can't get the exact one, (b) he prefers another kind, or (c) code changes require a different kind of pump. In any case, a circulator pump is a very common component in hydronic systems, and there are probably lots of models that will work just fine in your situation. However, if this heat zone has been unused/unmaintained for a very long time, I wouldn't be surprised if your plumber finds other problems besides the pump.

Comment: Um. Google 'UP 15-42 F' and you'll find new and used models for sale on eBay and other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that loop is unused then it would probably be just as easy to replace the pump with another brand that fits the gap. If you can find a local shop that has a new Grundfos or Taco pump that has the same size fittings and gap between them you could swap a new one in. You could easily find one with the same GPM rating.